# SQL Update a table from same table join

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

Below is 2 views of same table "TablePDF" I need a UPDATE statement that can join the 2 views based on same table and update the T_File column in View1 with the value of T_FILE in View2 CustOrdNumber = CustOrdNumber AND WebLineNum = Occurence

**examples of updated values based on the 2 joined field**

```
102597-RPI-2012756206310402-1-A.pdf = 102597-RPI-2012756206310402-1-A.pdf
102597-RPI-2012756206310402-11-A.pdf = 102597-RPI-2012756206310402-17-A.pdf
102597-RPI-2012756206310402-13-A.pdf - 102597-RPI-2012756206310402-5-A.pdf
```

TablePDF _View1

```
**T_File|lineseqnum|WebLineNum|CustOrdNumber**

102407-FA-20140208300311402-2-A.pdf 32768   0   102407-FA

102407-FA-2014345208310402-1-A.pdf  16384   0   102407-FA

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-1-A.pdf 114688  1   102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-11-A.pdf    147456  17  102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-13-A.pdf    16384   5   102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-15-A.pdf    180224  9   102597-RPI
```

TablePDF _View2

```
**T_File|lineseqnum|occurence|CustOrdNumber**

102407-FA-20140208300311402-2-A.pdf 32768   2   102407-FA

102407-FA-2014345208310402-1-A.pdf  16384   1   102407-FA

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-1-A.pdf 114688  1   102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-11-A.pdf    147456  11  102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-13-A.pdf    16384   13  102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-15-A.pdf    180224  15  102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-17-A.pdf    212992  17  102597-RPI

102597-RPI-2012756206310402-19-A.pdf    245760  19  102597-RPI
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: I edited my question, what I need is to update the T_File field based on select from same table as I explain above.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't update column values inside VIEWS, views are meant to select data from table; they don't actually stores values inside them.

You can use following,

```
SELECT B.T_File FROM TablePDF_View1 A INNER JOIN TablePDF_View2 B
ON A.CustOrdNumber = B.CustOrdNumber
AND A.WebLineNum = B.Occurence
```

and use this column to update your TablePDF table using further join with table TablePDF on possible unique columns in joins.

Comment: Wrong. views can be updated. [read this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx)